# How can I start to write my final paper?

Tags: writing, emotional-responses

How can I start to write my final paper? I have been doing nothing during the whole week. I just stayed at home and slept. I'm afraid to do anything even cooking. I can't focus and can't concentrate on work. I'm just afraid to write a single sentence. I don't know how to start. I mean that I know how to write but I just can't start. I am incredibly anxious and don't know how to get started. Can anyone  help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources on how to overcome writer's block, especially for non-native English speakers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/resources-on-how-to-overcome-writers-block-especially-for-non-native-english-s)

Answer (score 2):

Getting started writing can be very hard—if it weren't, it wouldn't have a name: [writer's block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writer%27s_block).

There are a lot of different strategies you could try:

- **Free writing.** Just write anything that comes to your mind as you think about your topic. Don't worry about grammar or correctness or appropriateness or accuracy. Just put down something. (You can handwrite it or type it, as you see fit).
- **Mind map.** Just put together a flow diagram showing how different things you want to write about are related.
- **Create an outline.** Don't focus on writing the whole essay, or even whole paragraphs or sentences. Just try putting together a skeleton for what your essay should be like.

[There are a lot of other ideas for how to cure writer's block](https://goinswriter.com/how-to-overcome-writers-block/), including walking or even spending time with people who make you feel comfortable.

Comment: Thank you very much！ Your response let me successfully cried out. This lets my brain feel more free. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Take a deep breath.
Do you know how you want to frame your essay? Do you have it organized in your mind?
Try brainstorming your ideas and see if there is something cohesive to come out of it. 
Sometimes putting pen to paper is a better agitator of a good essay than sitting in front of word and trying to create something.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to make a face time with my friends and say nothing just hear her voice of breathing. When she was doing her assignment, I tried to type some thing. It helps me about one hour. When I stop this, and go back alone face my computer screen, I feel feet cold and stomach.