# Writing an arXiv paper without "Introduction" or "related work" sections

Tags: writing, writing-style, arxiv

Many conferences and journals demand that a paper must follow certain guidelines; otherwise the paper will not get accepted.
For example:

1. Writing introduction section
2. Writing previous related work

Is it okay to not follow these guidelines while writing an arXiv version? I want to directly write the main result and its proof, and put that on arXiv.

Note: I take an exceptionally good amount of time to write an Introduction since I am not good with framing English sentences. And since my research area is a competitive one, I do not want to get scooped in that time.

Comment: Related works is an important section of the paper to give the readers a sense as to why your method works better and why the others haven't. An intro can be compressed into the abstract but it is generally not recommended. May be cut short it into half and just specify the important points?

Answer (score 4):

ArXiv's [submission guidelines](https://arxiv.org/help/submit) state that

> Submissions to arXiv should be topical and refereeable scientific contributions that follow accepted standards of scholarly communication.

A manuscript that doesn't provide any context is unlikely to meet that standard, and may be declined by a [moderator](https://arxiv.org/help/moderation). In any case, the golden rule in technical communication is to consider the audience (hopefully your preprint will find some interested readers!) and what they'd find useful. Context and discussion of the relation to prior work tend to be quite useful.

Note, however, that ArXiv's guidelines don't specify that you need to write a *perfect* introduction. I've sometimes found myself stuck on one or two key opening sentences, trying to get them just right, instead of writing productively. If you face a similar issue, here's a method I've found useful. First consider what points you want to make, and maybe key works you want to cite, in order to have some structure to work from. Then force yourself to just put something down on (a possibly figurative) paper, in order to get started. If you edit that a few times, I would be surprised if you don't have something that's at least refereeable. More advice along these lines can be found [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7656/17254).